# How to find a linear injection $X\rightarrow X^\ast$ for general normed spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space. Is it always possible to have a linear injection $T:X\rightarrow X^\ast$ which associates to every vector in $X$ a unique functional in $X^\ast$?

I suspect this is not the case, but the space $X$ with which I am working has no more structure than a normed space, yet I find myself wanting to produce functionals from a specific family of vectors I have on hand.

Comment: Does this injection have to be linear?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes

Comment: Question: is this a finite dimensional space? What more information can you give us about it?

Comment: @CameronWilliams X is not necessarily finite dimensional

Comment: @CameronWilliams There is one well-studied non-linear injection for smooth spaces: the duality map. Basically, you map $0$ to $0$, and each other vector $x$ to the unique linear functional that supports that point on the ball $B[0; \|x\|]$. I believe that such a map is linear if and only if the space is an inner product space.

Comment: You could do something "stupid" and just linearly order the basis vectors and associate them that way, but that is a _completely_ unhelpful injection.

Comment: @TheoBendit Interesting! It makes some sense though.

Comment: The space I’m working with is just a normed space. It would also be acceptable to consider X a Banach space, but X definitely doesn’t have an inner product structure (or a norm satisfying the parallelogram identity).

Comment: @TheoBendit This is very helpful

Comment: Fundamentally, without an inner product or self-dual structure (like $L^p \times L^q$ where $p$ and $q$ are conjugates (or more generally $X\times X^*$)), I don't know if there's a useful way to do this that isn't just done at the basis vector level (which doesn't really achieve anything).

Comment: @SawyerR. I'm not really expert on the duality map, but I can put this into an answer if you want?

Comment: @TheoBendit Don’t worry about writing it up! I will look into this mapping. Thank you